# Need to run 'composer update' on ssh on hostgator, but php -v to low

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

Need Help

Framework - Laravel

Hosting - Hostgator

Problem Statement :- I need to run the 'composer update'. All dependencies required minimun php -v of 5.5.9. I have manualy Upgrade the php version of Project directory to 5.6 from cpanel using 'Php configration' plugin. But when i logged in using ssh, then i got the php -v of 5.4.45. Ofcourse It targeting the deafult php version of the server. Is there any way to update php to 5.6 or above on ssh also. No root user access. No help from support team also.

Comment: If you've tried to update PHP via cPanel but it's not updated on the server, you'll definitely need to talk to HostGator. Try their forums or open a ticket. You say there's no help, but they should be able to do something to update it.

Comment: This is because the `command line` (CLI) and the `webserver` are not running the same version of PHP. When executing functions over SSH, it's looking at the CLI. They should be the same version.

Comment: hi @aynber, Thanks but  I have already talked to hostgator, but they replied that they can't update the default php -v for shared hosting.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, yeah I know that, thats why i have mentioned that _"It targeting the deafult php version of the server"._ Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Indeed. I'm pointing out why you'll never be able to do this on a shared hosting environment. Not gonna happen. Pay $20 a month for `Laravel Forge` to manage your server, or buy a cheap VPS and build one out if you're feeling up to it.

Comment: Great, Nice suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

Use this command in ssh

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

then paste these lines, you can change php version after opt/php55 is 5.5, 71 is 7.1 accordingly

```
alias php='/opt/php71/bin/php'
alias composer='/opt/php71/bin/php ~/bin/composer'
export DRUSH_PHP='/opt/php71/bin/php'
```

Now, re-source the file so the command line gets the new aliases

```
 $ . ~/.bashrc
```

now check version

```
$ php --version
```

simple easy trick is if you want to run artisan commands using php7.1 then use this command

```
   $ /opt/php71/bin/php artisan
```

Comment: Nice! i did not know this was possible.  To get the php path : composer diagnose. For the php path i use the error message in composer slef-update commande

Comment: @Adnan - Great Job!!

Comment: i followed the instructions but I got the message Could not open input file: /home1/username/bin/composer. What should I do?

Comment: Please upload "composer.phar"   file in bin/composer   folder  and then try it.  
You can download file from https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: `alias composer='/opt/php71/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer'`

Comment: @HeliPerez your version works on my HG account.. thanks!

Comment: You are great @Adnan. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Using a PRO/Shared Host (tested in Hostgator.com.br) you can do this in SSH (change the usercpanel to your own):

```
vim /home/usercpanel/.bashrc
```

In the next page, if it's blank, insert the values:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
 . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
```

Right after, you will put (you can change the php version: 71, 72, 73 or 74):

```
alias php='/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php'
export PATH="/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

[image: Will be like this]

Save the changes and exit.

Now, insert this code to load the new config (change the usercpanel to your own):

```
source /home/usercpanel/.bashrc
```

And, insert this code to verify if the alias has been loaded.

```
alias | egrep 'php'
```

And then, check if the path is being displayed in the PATH variable:

```
echo $PATH | egrep '/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin'
```

DONE! Tested and working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Recently i update composer and also php in my **mac_system**
  And used these commands by **terminal**

-Local php update in Mac os  curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0

-export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH   (change php version to create project)

[php update](http://php-osx.liip.ch/)

This above link.. i Used.. So try with command or the link.
  I think you will get some knowledge on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help man, but I think OS X version is not updated on the server,
got this message on terminal "Your version of OS X () is not supported, you need at least 10.6"

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a workaround to get newer versions of php and composer working via ssh on shared hosting env such as hostgator.

Try to add the following lines to your .bash_profile or .bashrc and resource your bash shell. The default version of PHP should now be changed to whatever version you specified.

```
alias php='/opt/php{VERSION_NUMBER}/bin/php'
alias composer='/opt/php{VERSION_NUMBER}/bin/php ~/bin/composer'
export DRUSH_PHP='/opt/php{VERSION_NUMBER}/bin/php'
```

Use php -v to check the version of php and test if composer works.
If composer still doesn't work install it in the ~/bin/composer folder following the instructions First install composer using the instruction https://getcomposer.org/download/.

At least thats what I did!

Answer (score 1):

Just for others who are suffering like me.

You can use my trick in Hostgator command line (CLI). It works for me every time when I want to use CLI with Laravel 5.6 (required PHP 7.1) on Hostgator shared hosting.

```
$ /opt/php71/bin/php /home/{your_directory}/composer.phar update
```

I have a few Laravel projects on the same shared hosting so **{your_directory}** can be change depending on your project directory path.

Comment: on share hostings if you don't want to mess with the default path, this is a good way also 
/opt/php71/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer install

Answer (score 0):

Using aliases did not work for me. Actually composer did work, but when it called ran artisan, errors such as "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class'" appeared (php5 was used instead of php7)

Instead I had to copy `/opt/php71/bin/php` to `~/home/bin` then modify `~/.bash_profile` to use my local bin path first

```
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

(and I ran `. ~/.bash_profile` afterwards to apply changes)

Would have prefered a symbolic link with `ln -s /opt/php71/bin/php ~/bin` but it did not work (permission denied).